# Passing array with ajax - can't print

Tags: php, sql, ajax, parsing

I hope this problem is very simple, I can't figure out the solution myself it seems. Been trying and googling for hours, driving me nuts :) Ok, so I have a drag'n'drop + sortable (using scriptaculous and prototype for your information) on my *index.php*. I use this code to send the items dropped in a div using this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[  
    document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {  
        var changeEffect;  
    Sortable.create("selectedSetupTop", {containment: ['listStr', 'selectedSetupTop'], tag:'img', overlap:'vertical', constraint:false, dropOnEmpty: true,
        onChange: function(item) {
            var list = Sortable.options(item).element;
            $('changeNotification').update(Sortable.serialize(list).escapeHTML());
            if(changeEffect) changeEffect.cancel();
            changeEffect = new Effect.Highlight('changeNotification', {restoreColor:"transparent" });
        },          
        onUpdate: function(list) {
            new Ajax.Request("script.php", {
                method: "post",
                parameters: { data: Sortable.serialize(list), container: list.id }
                onLoading: function(){$('activityIndicator').show(), $('activityIndicator2').hide()},
                onLoaded: function(){$('activityIndicator').hide(), $('activityIndicator2').show()},
            });             
        }
        });
    });  
// ]]>  
</script>
```

I've been using this code before so I "kind of know" it will send me data to my *script.php* page. *selectedSetupTop* is my div containing the elements. Don't mind about the *notification* and the *activityIndicator* thingy. My *script.php* page looks like this for the moment:

```
parse_str($_POST['data']);  
for ($i = 0; $i < count($selectedSetupTop); $i++) {  
    $test .= $selectedSetupTop[$i];
}

echo "<script>alert('$test');</script>";
```

I can't seem to get any output in the alert message, it's just blank. The purpose of the *script.php* is to update a row in a database and it will look kind of like this:

```
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE table SET row = '$arrayInStringFormat' WHERE id = '1'") or die(mysql_error());
```

where the **$arrayInStringFormat** is a conversion of the array **$selectedSetupTop** to the format (1, 2, 3, 4). I guess I'll solve that using implode or something, but the problem is parsing the array **$selectedSetupTop**. I'm not it passes between the pages at all, really appreciate help! Tell me if I need to explain further.

Thanks in advance!

## *''''''*

### EDIT 1

If it will help, I used this code before that I know will send me the data and use it. Notice I don't wanna do my task like the way I do below:

```
$querySetup = $_GET["s"];
parse_str($_POST['data']);  
for ($i = 0; $i < count($selectedSetupTop); $i++) {  
    $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE " . $querySetup . " SET orderId = $i, hero_selected = 'n' WHERE imageId = $selectedSetupTop[$i]") or die(mysql_error());    
}
```

## *''''''*

### EDIT 2

So it does parse, but I still have the problem I can't print it. I wanna implode the array somehow.

Comment: Use FireFox + Firebug' "NET" tab to see what data is going back and forth. It may give you a clue.

Comment: @Diodeus Thanks for the advice! I just did that and it seems it's not being passed. Do you see anything that might be wrong in the code?

Comment: Forget the previous comment, it does send! Checked params instead of post.

Comment: But I still have a problem printing it on my script.php page.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how AJAX works in Scriptalicious/Prototype, but you don't seem to be getting the data from the AJAX call. In jQuery it would be something like this where the data you receive from the script is returned as the argument of the function.

```
onLoaded: function(msg){
    $('activityIndicator').hide(),
    $('activityIndicator2').show(),
    alert(msg)
}
```

Secondly, you can't echo a PHP array, you have to encode it to JSON:

```
echo json_encode($test);
```

Comment: Right, but I meant the callback function to receive data.

Comment: According to Firebug it goes send me data. Looks like this:
container selectedSetupTop
data selectedSetupTop[]=19&selectedSetupTop[]=1&selectedSetupTop[]=54&selectedSetupTop[]=2